# making a search engine in python django

Tags: python, search

I've made a search feature using the python 2.7 **toned** package but to make it more scalable, I want to use ElasticSearch.
I want to do boolean searches like

```
(blue or small) purse and not leather
```

- Do I need haystack or just using an ElasticSearch client is enough?
- How can I do complex unpredictable boolean search like the example above (the boolean structure of the words is unknown)?

All I find in the docs is SearchQuery which requires me to know the search combination prior to run time.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated I figured out:

- I do not need haystack as all.
- boolean search can be done via a "simple query search" method in elastic search however it uses "+-|" instead of "AND" "NOT" "OR" so it's just a matter of word replacement.
- You can overwrite the search of the admin page to use elasticsearch, then apply the filter query over that. However, elastic search can return no more than 10000 results per page...you can read multiple pages but I ended up retrieving only the first 10000 ids (if there are more than 10000 results) and passing it to admin to do a query `mymodel.objects.filter(id__in=[my_ids])`

I'm not very happy about doing this so if someones know a better way, let me know.